# ¿Como quitar un salto de linea vbcr en VBA Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Estoy haciendo un programa y necesito ordenar de esta manera la información.

```
Datos      Fechas

Dato 1   xx/xx/xxxx
Dato 2   xx/xx/xxxx
Dato 3   xx/xx/xxxx
```

Mi problema es que tengo un array donde guardo los datos y las fechas por separado, y cuando las imprimo las hago con un vbCr; Donde aparecen de la siguiente manera.

```
Datos      Fechas
Dato 1   
Dato 2   
Dato 3   

xx/xx/xxxx
xx/xx/xxxx
xx/xx/xxxx
```

He estado buscando algún comando que me elimine los saltos que he puesto con el vbcr pero no he encontrado hasta ahora ninguna solución.

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Suena a que podrías beneficiarte de `Replace`